# Black screen flashes on second monitor on Ubuntu 16

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, flash, screen

I upgrade my Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 yesterday and after fixing some hiccups most things are working fine.

However, I have one very annoying bug that lets my external monitor (connected to the laptop) randomly flash black from time to time. The flashes are not longer than one second and then everything works fine again.

My suspicion is that flash makes some issues here as it appears to happen more frequently while watching a flash video in firefox.

Comment: do you have chrome installed?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I do.

Comment: does the issue occur with flash in that?

Comment: I can try...however it also occurs in VLC.

Comment: What hardware are you using? Let us see you X config.

Comment: I just figured out that it might be a problem with my Dell monitor. At work, I had no black flashes today with a different external monitor. It definitely worked before the upgrade though.

Comment: I'm also having that issue after installing Kubuntu Xenial and I'm also having two Dells monitors and only one is doing.

Comment: Have not found a solution yet unfortunately...

Comment: a similar bug affects me too.
But I suspect this bug is caused by a fail in graphics driver, I think this because my secondary monitor also goes when I type anything in gnome-terminal.